# Unexpected Program Stoppage on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller

I have an issue where my Arduino program hangs for no reason. I run my program, and at some undetermined point, the Serial Monitor stops printing output. Here's what I've tested so far:

- In my "com.init_drone()" method, I've commented everything out except for the last line, which signals that the method returned. When I do this, my program hangs somewhere else but still it doesn't get to the infinite while loop.
- I've been outputting memory usage, and I'm getting numbers no lower than 450 -- this tells me that I'm not using an absurd amount of memory.
- I've tried removing the Timer1 instantiation, interrupt attach/detach, bu that has had no effect on the program.

My [.ino file(and Command) is located here](https://github.com/hwrdprkns/SeniorProject/blob/timerTroubles/ATCommand/) for anyone that wants a fuller picture and doesn't want to scroll through all this code I'm going to post below.

---

Here's my log output so far. **Notice the truncation!**:

```
AT&F
AT+NMAC=00:1d:c9:10:39:6f
AT+WM=0
AT+NDHCP=1
AT+WA=ardrone_279440
AT+NCUDP=192.168.1.1,5556
S0AT*CONFIG=1,"general:navdata_demo","TRUE"
EAT*CONFIG=1,"general:navdata_demo","TRUE"

638
S0AT*CONFIG=2,"control:altitude_max","2000"
EAT*CONFIG=2,"control:altitude_max","2000"

638
S0AT*CONFIG=3,"control:euler_angle_max","0.35"
EAT*CONFIG=3,"control:euler_angle_max","0.35"

586
S0AT*CONFIG=4,"control:outdoor","FALSE"
EAT*CONFIG=4,"control:outdoor","FALSE"

635
S0AT*CONFIG=5,"control:flight_without_shell","FALSE"
EAT*CONFIG=5,"control:flight_without_shell","FALSE"

574
S0AT*CTRL=6,4,0
EAT*CTRL=6,4,0

629
S0AT*CTRL=7,0,0
EAT*CTRL=7,0,0

629
S0AT*CTRL=8,4,0
EAT*CTRL=8,4,0

629
S0AT*COMWDG=9
EAT*COMWDG=9

629
S0AT*COMWDG=10
EAT*COMWDG=10

629
S0AT*COMWDG=11
EAT*COMWDG=11

629
S0AT*COMWDG=12
EAT*COMWDG=12

629
S0AT*COMWDG=13
EAT*COMWDG=13

629
S0AT*FTRIM=14
EAT*FTRIM=14

629
```

Here is my .ino file:

```cpp
#include "Command.h"
#include "Streaming.h"

int debug = 1;
extern ring_buffer rx_buf;
extern resultint_ resultint;

Command com;
int sequenceNumber = 1;
String atcmd = "";

#include "TimerOne.h"
#define LEDpin 13



void setup()
{
  PCsrl.begin(9600);

  com.start_wifi_connection();

  com.drone_is_init = com.init_drone();

  Timer1.initialize(COMWDG_INTERVAL_USEC);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(watchdog_timer);

}

void watchdog_timer() {
  com.sendwifi(com.makeComwdg());
}

void loop()
{  

  if (com.drone_is_init == 0) {
        if (debug) {
      // never use three ! together in arduino code
      PCsrl.println("Drone wasn't initlized before loop() was called. Initalizing now.\r\n");
    }

  } else {

    com.drone_takeoff();
    com.drone_takeoff();

    com.sendwifi(com.makePcmd(1,0,0,0,0));
    com.sendwifi(com.makePcmd(1,0,0,0,0));
    delay(5000);

    com.moveForward(1);
    com.moveRotate(180);
    com.moveForward(1);
    com.moveRotate(180);

    delay(500);

    com.drone_landing();
    com.drone_landing();

    delay(500);

    //end of program
    Timer1.detachInterrupt();
    PCsrl.println("Program finished");
    while (1){};

  }
}
```

And my Command.cpp

```cpp
#ifndef GAINSPAN
#define GAINSPAN
#include "Command.h"

extern int sequenceNumber;
extern int debug;

ring_buffer rx_buf= {{0}, 0, 0};
resultint_ resultint;


Command::Command()
{
  at = "";
  command = "";
  s2ip_running = 0;
  drone_is_init = 0;
  drone_is_hover = 0;
  emergency = 0;
}


void Command::sendwifi(String s) {

    WIFIsrl.write(27); //esc
    WIFIsrl.print("S0"); //choose connection CID 0
    WIFIsrl.print(s);
    WIFIsrl.write(27);
    WIFIsrl.print("E");


    if(debug) PCsrl.println(s);

    WIFIsrl.println(memoryTest()); 
}



int Command::start_wifi_connection()
{
  WIFIsrl.begin(9600);

  WIFIsrl.println("");
  WIFIsrl.println("AT&F");
  //WIFIsrl.println("ATE0"); //turn off echo
  WIFIsrl.print("AT+NMAC=00:1d:c9:10:39:6f\r"); //set MAC address
  WIFIsrl.println("AT+WM=0");

  WIFIsrl.println("AT+NDHCP=1");

  /* drone's network profile, change if needed*/
  WIFIsrl.println("AT+WA=ardrone_279440");
  WIFIsrl.println("AT+NCUDP=192.168.1.1,5556");
  readARsrl();

  delay(3000); //need 3 seconds for connection to establish
  return 0;
}  

String Command::makeComwdg()
{
  at = "AT*COMWDG=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "\r\n";
  return command;
}

void Command::sendComwdg_t(int msec)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < msec; i+=20) {
    sendwifi(makeComwdg());
    delay(20);
  }
}

void Command::sendFtrim()
{
  at = "AT*FTRIM=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "\r\n";
  sendwifi(command);
}

void Command::sendConfig(String option, String value)
{
  at = "AT*CONFIG=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + ",\"" + option + "\",\"" + value + "\"\r\n";
  sendwifi(command);
}

void Command::sendRef(flying_status fs)
{
  at = "AT*REF=";
  if(fs == TAKEOFF){
    command = at + getSequenceNumber() + ",290718208\r\n"; //takeoff
  }
  else if(fs == LANDING){
    command = at + getSequenceNumber() + ",290717696\r\n"; //landing
  } else if (fs == EMERGENCY_TOGGLE){
    command = at + getSequenceNumber() + ",290717952\r\n"; //landing
  }

  // emergency -> 290717952
  sendwifi(command);
}

void Command::send_control_commands(){
    at = "AT*CTRL=";
    sendwifi(at+getSequenceNumber()+",4,0\r\n");
    sendwifi(at+getSequenceNumber()+",0,0\r\n");
    sendwifi(at+getSequenceNumber()+",4,0\r\n");
}

void Command::drone_emergency_reset()
{
  at = "AT*REF=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + ",290717952\r\n";
  sendwifi(command);
}

/** Movement functions **/
int Command::moveForward(float distanceInMeters)
{
  float i = 0;
  String moveForward = makePcmd(1, 0, -.855, 0, 0);
  delay(1000*distanceInMeters);
  sendPcmd(moveForward);
  return 1;
}

int Command::moveRotate(float yawInDegrees)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < yawInDegrees) {
    String stayRotate = makePcmd(1, 0, 0, 0, 0.17);
    sendPcmd(stayRotate);
    delay(150);
    i += 8;
  }
  return 1;
}

String Command::makePcmd(int enable, float roll, float pitch, float gaz, float yaw)
{
  at = "AT*PCMD=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "," + enable + "," + fl2int(roll) + "," + fl2int(pitch) + "," + fl2int(gaz) + "," + fl2int(yaw) + "\r";
  return command;
}

void Command::sendPcmd(String command)
{
  previousCommand = command;
  sendwifi(command);
}

void Command::sendPcmd(int enable, float roll, float pitch, float gaz, float yaw)
{
  at = "AT*PCMD=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "," + enable + "," + fl2int(roll) + "," + fl2int(pitch) + "," + fl2int(gaz) + "," + fl2int(yaw) + "\r";
  sendwifi(command);
}

String Command::makeAnim(anim_mayday_t anim, int time)
{
  at = "AT*ANIM=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "," + anim + "," + time + "\r\n";
  return command;
}

void Command::doLEDAnim(int animseq, int duration)
{
  PCsrl << "calling LEDAnim" << endl;
  at = "AT*LED=";
  command = at + getSequenceNumber() + "," + animseq + ",1073741824," + duration + "\r\n";
  sendwifi(command);
}

int Command::start_s2ip()
{
  char temp;
  //delay(20000); //wait for drone to start

  readARsrl();

  if (debug) {
    PCsrl << "trying to start s2ip" << endl;
  }

  ARsrl.print("\r\n");
  delay(500);
  ARsrl.print("\r\n");
  delay(500);
  ARsrl << "cd ~" << endl;

  if (debug) {
    readARsrl();
  }

  delay(500);
  ARsrl << "cd data/video/apps/" << endl;
  delay(500);
  ARsrl << "./s2ip.arm" << endl; 
  while ((int) temp != 2) {
    temp = ARsrl.read();
    if (temp == 2) {
      PCsrl << "s2ip is running" << endl;
      ARsrl << "bullshit\r\n"; //to fix a delay bug
      break;
    }
    //PCsrl << "s2ip not running" << endl;
  }
  if (debug) {
    while (ARsrl.available()) {
      PCsrl.write(ARsrl.read());
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

void Command::quit_s2ip()
{
  ARsrl.println("EXIT");
  while (ARsrl.available()) {
    PCsrl.write(ARsrl.read()); 
  }
}

int Command::init_drone()
{
  sendConfig("general:navdata_demo","TRUE");
  sendConfig("control:altitude_max","2000");
  sendConfig("control:euler_angle_max","0.35");
  sendConfig("control:outdoor","FALSE");
  sendConfig("control:flight_without_shell","FALSE");
  send_control_commands();
  sendComwdg_t(90);
  sendFtrim();

  drone_emergency_reset(); //clear emergency flag

  return 1;
}

int Command::drone_takeoff()
{
  sendRef(TAKEOFF);
  int i = 0;
  return 1;
}

int Command::drone_hover(int msec)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < msec) {
    sendwifi(makePcmd(1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    delay(100);
    i += 100;
  }
  return 1;
}

int Command::drone_landing()
{
  sendRef(LANDING);
  return 1;
}

int Command::drone_move_up(int centimeter)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < centimeter) {
    ARsrl << makePcmd(1, 0, 0, 0.6, 0);
    delay(100);
    i += 10;
  }
  return 1;
}

int Command::drone_move_down(int centimeter)
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < centimeter) {
    sendwifi(makePcmd(1, 0, 0, -0.5, 0));
    delay(100);
    i += 10;
  }
  return 1;
}

long Command::fl2int(float value)
{
  resultint.i = 0;
  if (value < -1 || value > 1) {
    resultint.f = 1;
  } else {
    resultint.f=value;
  }

  return resultint.i;
}

void Command::readARsrl()
{
  while (ARsrl.available()) {
    if (debug) {
      PCsrl.write(ARsrl.read());
    }
  }
}


//Memory test code from : http://www.faludi.com/2007/04/18/arduino-available-memory-test/
int Command::memoryTest() {
  int byteCounter = 0; // initialize a counter
  byte *byteArray; // create a pointer to a byte array
  // More on pointers here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer#C_pointers

  // use the malloc function to repeatedly attempt
  // allocating a certain number of bytes to memory
  // More on malloc here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc
  while ( (byteArray = (byte*) malloc (byteCounter * sizeof(byte))) != NULL ) {
    byteCounter++; // if allocation was successful, then up the count for the next try
    free(byteArray); // free memory after allocating it
  }

  free(byteArray); // also free memory after the function finishes
  return byteCounter; // send back the highest number of bytes successfully allocated
}

int Command::getSequenceNumber(){
  return sequenceNumber++;
}

// Volatile, since it is modified in an ISR.
volatile boolean inService = false;

void SrlRead()
{
  if (inService) {
    PCsrl.println("timer kicked too fast");
    return;
  }
  interrupts();
  inService = true;
  while(ARsrl.available()) {
    unsigned char k = ARsrl.read();
    store_char(k, &rx_buf);
  }
  inService = false;
}

void read_rx_buf()
{
  while (rx_buf.tail != rx_buf.head) {
    if (debug) {
      PCsrl.write(rx_buf.buffer[rx_buf.tail]);
    }
    rx_buf.tail = (unsigned int) (rx_buf.tail+ 1) % SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;
  }
}

inline void store_char(unsigned char c, ring_buffer *buffer)
{
  int i = (unsigned int)(buffer->head + 1) % SERIAL_BUFFER_SIZE;

  // if we should be storing the received character into the location
  // just before the tail (meaning that the head would advance to the
  // current location of the tail), we're about to overflow the buffer
  // and so we don't write the character or advance the head.
  if (i != buffer->tail) {
    buffer->buffer[buffer->head] = c;
    buffer->head = i;
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("ring buffer is too small");
  }
}

#endif
```

Comment: If you want to check available memory, I'd suggest using the (first) mechanism described here: http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory. The `memoryTest` routine in your code allocates and deallocates memory which is quite an invasive (and time consuming) way of calculating free memory.

Comment: You are calling `Serial.begin()` twice in quick succession, first in `setup()` (using `#define PCsrl Serial`) and then in `start_wifi_connection()` (using `#define WIFIsrl Serial`). I'm not sure how this could cause the hanging but might be worth commenting out one just to check.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch: I didn't even notice that. It didn't fix the problem, but it was a bug in my code. Thanks!

Comment: what is your memory usage? is your stack colliding with other data?

Comment: @dwelch: Notice my log output. It says I have ~600 bytes free. So I have about (stackLength) - ~600 ... I don't see why there would be collisions... In that case I would just get corrupted data, no?

Comment: the memory test is very scary.  I dont know how your memory layout looks but if the malloc collides with the stack you could/would see what you are seeing or worse.  The simplest result is seeing the strings change, either longer or shorter.  But a stack and heap/data collision could/would cause hangs and other crashes as well in general.  I doubt an arduino malloc is elaborate enough for this.  malloc/free on embedded, esp an avr, is not a good idea, but there is a lot here that is scary for such a platform.  A disassembly would tell a lot about the memory map if you dont already know

Comment: so it gets up to drone_emergency_reset() and fails somewhere around there?  the other output looks okay yes?

Comment: Right. I think I got it fixed, though. I used a different memory function (the library one that @MatthewMurdoch suggested) and then started to put stuff in `prog` memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I started to put things in `prog` memory my program started to clear up it's hiccups. It seems it was a memory issue.

Comment: Looking over your code it has huge amounts of 'bloat' for a tiny microcontroller. Things like "ring buffer is too small" that should be unusual exceptions could be a call to something like signal_exception(10) that outputs something like '~10'. And other things like sendPcmd could just call makePcmd followed by sending it. But regardless you're right constant strings are best put in program memory, and lots of those local string constants could be moved as well to free up more RAM.

Answer (score 2):

I know it sounds weird but, sometimes this happens when arduino is not getting enough power supply. Try connecting the arduino to a power source different from USB.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the issue was with `Timer1.initialize()`. Try this:

```
  com.drone_is_init = com.init_drone();

  Serial.println("One");
  Serial.println("Two");
  Serial.println("Three");

  Timer1.initialize(COMWDG_INTERVAL_USEC);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(watchdog_timer);
```

Open serial monitor and see... it will show until "Two", and then Arduino will hang.

The issue was I calling some functions of the LiquidCrystal_I2C library, that need interrupt routines. Check if your timer ISR is using some interrupts. If so, you should move this code to another place in your project.